# Java Queue BlockingQueue<Arraylist<Object>>

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, blockingqueue

I am working on a program (mostly for learning) in which a producer thread will read in a file to an arraylist and then store this into a que, The consumer will then take this ArrayList and do some string manipulation (while simultaneity the producer is scanning the next file into the second arraylist queue.

The issue I am running into is when I pass a single string line the queue works perfectly! However as soon as I pass it an Arraylist (while it can print this Arraylist) will only access the last immediate addition to the queue

Example Single String Output
     Produce File 201
     Produce File 202
     Produce File 203
     Consumed file 201
     Produce File 204
     Consumed file 202

Example ArrayList
     produce File 201
     Produce File 202
     Produce File 203
     Consume File 203
     Produce File 204
     Produce File 205
     Consume File 205

Any Idea why this is?

Comment: Post your code...

Comment: @IvanPronin The code is quit long and expansive (between main/producer/consumer ect)

instead of queue.put(STRING) I use queue.put(ARRAYLIST<OBJECT>) and when this is done queue.take() no longer works properly as stated above. I've set all queue's to queue<ArrayList<Object>> but still doesn't take() correctly. Ironirally passing ArrayList<Object>.toString() will take() correctly.

Comment: My suggestion would be to double check that you are not modifying the array after you call the put method. Perhaps you are not creating a new instance of your array for each put. However without code this is really a shot in the dark.

Comment: @alan7678 I will comment back with some code examples. 

I will try your suggestion thank you!